# Set input button value to same name but uppercase

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to update the value of a input button to the same name as before, but as uppercase. I struggle with calling the button value within the button value and keep getting errors. This is what I got now:

```
function updateButton(button) {
    $(button).val(button.val().ToUpperCase())
}
```

The error I get is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: button.val is not a function
```

HTML:

```
<input type='button' id='btn1' value='test' class='btn' onclick='updateButton(this)'>
<input type='button' id='btn2' value='test' class='btn' onclick='updateButton(this)'>
<input type='button' id='btn3' value='test' class='btn' onclick='updateButton(this)'>
```

Any idea on how to update the value within itself?

Comment: can you also share the html? Also it is [**toUpperCase**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toUpperCase)

Comment: `$(button).val(button.value.toUpperCase())` or `$(button).val(function(i, v){ return v.toUpperCase(); })`

Comment: Maybe because `button` does not have `value` attribute?

Comment: wrap button in $ again `$(button).val($(button).val().toUpperCase())`

Comment: replace   ` button.val().ToUpperCase()`    to   `button.val.ToUpperCase() `

Comment: First, `button` implies a variable (you may have meant `$('button')`), and second a `<button>` element doesn't have a `value` attribute. So presumably you'd need `$('button').text(function(){ return this.name.toUppercase(); });`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$(button).val($(button).val().toUpperCase());
```

the second button needs to be wrapped by jQuery as well, and the toUpperCase starts with (oh the irony) a lower-case t.

Comment: Works perfectly. Will accept as soon as I can. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Firstly note that the method to change case is `toUpperCase()`, not `ToUpperCase()`.

From the error you're getting it would appear that the `button` variable contains a DOMElement, not a jQuery object, and hence the error when trying to access jQuery's `val()` method. Instead, you could use the `value` property of the DOMElement directly:

```
function updateButton(button) {
    $(button).val(button.value.toUpperCase())
}
```

Better still, you could use unobtrusive JavaScript to attach your event handlers:

```js
$('.btn').click(function() {
  $(this).val(this.value.toUpperCase());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='button' id='btn1' value='test' class='btn' />
<input type='button' id='btn2' value='test' class='btn' />
<input type='button' id='btn3' value='test' class='btn' />
```

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing jQuery objects with other js variables. `$(button)` is a jQuery object which selects all elements of type button, while `button` is simply a variable and if not defined before is of type `undefined`.

```
var button = $(button);
function updateButton(button) {
    button.val(button.val().toUpperCase())
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting as `.val()` is jQuery method and you are using it with native DOM element.

You need to create  a jQuery object to use `.val()`, manipulation can be achieved using `val(fn)` method

```
$(button).val(function(_, value){
    return value.toUpperCase()
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest:

```
// select all <input> elements with a 'type' attribute
// equal to 'button'; then use the on() method - and
// its anonymous function - to bind the anonymous
// function as the 'click' event-handler:
$('input[type=button]').on('click', function(){

    // set the value of the current element -
    // 'this' will be the clicked input element -
    // to the string-value of its name attribute
    // set to uppercase:
    this.value = this.name.toUpperCase();
});
```

Answer (score -1):

$('#button_id').val(button.val().ToUpperCase())

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
        function updateButton(button) {
          $(button).val($(button).val().toUpperCase());
        }
    </script>
    <input type="button" value="hello" onclick="updateButton(this)">
```

Comment: Explain why to `try this` and why it's solving issue

Comment: @Justinas i can't answer the first but the 't' in 'toUpperCase' must be lowercase